# C# .Net 6 Can't hit API route

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm not able to hit my api routes on new project I configured even though everything looks right.

Controller looks like

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;
    private readonly ILogger<AccountController> _logger;

    public AccountController(IMapper mapper, UserManager<User> userManager, SignInManager<User> signInManager, ILogger<AccountController> logger)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet("/Test")]
    public String Test()
    {
        var z = 7;
        return "Route Hit";
    }
}
```

and I've tried various requests such as

```
https://localhost:5001/api/account/test
https://localhost:5001/api/account/Test
https://localhost:5001/api/Account/test
https://localhost:5001/api/Account/Test
https://localhost:5001/api/AccountController/Test
https://localhost:5001/api/AccountController/test
```

but all of them return a 404 error.

Why might that be? Everything looks correct from what I see. This is on a project I was converting from MVC app to Web API

[image: Example pic]

Comment: Show the route file. Did you tried https://localhost:5001/Test or https://localhost:5001/api/Test ?

Comment: wow localhost:5001/Test works do you know the reason? I added route     [Route("api/[controller]")] to the top of the controller so I thought it would have to add that to the route param

Comment: Because you set [HttpGet("/Test")] and the / is from the root. You should configure this on route file

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, if you add this as a answer I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By request of the OP.

This should be configurated in `route` file

But the slash is taken from the root, so you must remove it to made it as relative path.

```
    [HttpGet("Test")]
    public String Test()
    {
        var z = 7;
        return "Route Hit";
    }
```

or complete the sequence from the root.

```
    [HttpGet("/api/account/Test")]
    public String Test()
    {
        var z = 7;
        return "Route Hit";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the slash in your Httpget attribute as follows

```
[HttpGet("Test")]
public String Test()
{
    var z = 7;
    return "Route Hit";
}
```